How do you solve $S=\lfloor\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\rfloor$
$$S=\lfloor\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\rfloor$$
Obviously I do not expect a nice closed form to this sum, I am explicitly looking for finding nice bounds to this expression $\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}$, so I can apply floor function, Here's one I managed to do,
$$\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}<\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}<1-\frac{1}{k^2}$$
But I am not sure if i can apply sum and then apply floor function here
I also learnt about the fact that applying floor function on an inequality requires you to prove that $k+1>A >k$,  only then can you say $\lfloor A \rfloor=k$, but if its not $k+1>A >k$ can i still apply floor function?

$(1-1/k)^{1/k} \ge (1-1/k)^{1/2}\ge (1/2)^{1/2}$ gives a linear in $n$ lower bound.

A better (not the optimal) lower bound is $(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$.

With $S,$ You're adding $n$ numbers, each one is close to $1,$ so their sum is approximately $n.$ Maybe slightly less like $n-1$ or $n-2.$

for instance i have managed to obtain this approximation $ \left( \frac{k}{k} \right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}<\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}< 1+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$, here applying the sum and applying floor function seems right, but a similar approximation for my above question does not seem nice to apply floor (if not the sum)

@ Amrut Ayan As per your second question: By definition, if $n\leq x<n+1$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor=n$. So, if you show that $x>n$ for some integer $n$, then $\lfloor x \rfloor\geq n$.

The sum appears to converge to $n-0.721477$. So probably the answer is $n-1$, but we need to prove $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(1- \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/k}\right) < 1$

@ aschepler. This inequality seems to be true too. Notice that the summand is asymptotically equivalent to $1/k^2$.

If, at least for the time being, we forget the floor, taking logarithms, using Taylor series and exponentiating again, we have
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}=1-\frac 1{k^2}-\frac{1}{2k^3}+\frac{1}{6 k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$
which provides upper and lower bounds.
Using this very truncated expansion for
$$S_n=\sum _{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
$$S_n=n+\frac{4}{3}  -H_{n+1}^{(2)}-\frac{1}{2}H_{n+1}^{(3)}+ \frac{1}{6} H_{n+1}^{(4)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers.
For $n=10$, the above gives $9.3565$ while the exact value is $9.3673$
If $n$ is large, this gives
$$S_n\sim n+C+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{5}{4n^2}+
\frac{49}{36 n^3}-\frac{9}{8n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
where $$C=\frac 43-\frac {\pi^2}6+\frac {\pi^4}{540}-\frac 12 \zeta(3)=-0.732242 $$
$$\large\color{blue}{\left\lfloor \sum _{k=2}^{n+1}
   \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}
   {k}}\right\rfloor=n-1}$$ is true even for small values of $n$. This was already said by @aschepler in comments.

Thank you sir, using the Taylor expansion to make bounds was an option I didn’t try..
